# xpath is not able to identify the webelement

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Following is the html of the element that I am trying to construct the xpath for:

```
<div class="b-list-item" data-index="7" data-id="8">
Jong
</div>
```

I tried the following xpaths none of them worked:

```
//div[text()='Jong']
//div[.='Jong']
//div[@class='b-list-item' and text()='Jong']
```

I need to use the text to construct the xpath, can someone help in achieving it.

Comment: Do you want to select the element by Text? If so make it clear in the description.
Post some more HTML for the element.

Comment: Can you find the element? or is it failing while performing any selenium operations like click, text etc. explain in detail so we can resolve the issue and put more HTML script so that we can clearly check whether this item is in frames or not etc etc

Comment: could you please check that 'John" embedded in DOM without any spaces before and after. 

Anyway following path should work: `//div[contains(@class, 'b-list-item') and contains(text(), 'Jong')]`

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that the text node containing `Jong` string has leading and trailing new line characters `&#xA;`.

Use the [`normalize-space()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) like this

```
//div[normalize-space()='Jong']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath `//div[@class='b-list-item']`, it should work

Answer (score 0):

I checked creating a dummy page with your given html elements and the below mentioned xpath has worked fine for me. Can you please try it?

`xpath=//div[@class='b-list-item' and contains(text(),'Jong')]`